# Keep changes on reload if validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rails-activerecord

I'm working with validations in rails, stuff like:

```
validates_presence_of :some_field
```

I've noticed that if the validation fails, all changes are overwritten with existing values from the database.  This makes some sense, as the page is basically being reloaded (as I gather from my development log), however this increases the risk of user error/frustration, as a single error in one field will require the hapless fellow to re-enter the changes he made to all fields.

**My question:**  How can I get rails to reload the data that was just **submitted** if validation fails?  That way, the user can correct the mistake without needing to re-enter the rest of his revisions.

Thanks for any advice.

**Edit:**
My update method, as requested, is as follows:

```
def update
    @incorporation = Incorporation.find(params[:id])
    @company = @incorporation.company
    begin
        @company.name="#{params[:company][:names_attributes].values.first["name_string"]} #{params[:company][:names_attributes].values.first["suffix"]}"
    rescue NoMethodError
        @company.name="Company #{@company.id} (Untitled)"
    end
    if @company.update(company_params)
        redirect_to incorporations_index_path
    else
        redirect_to edit_incorporation_path(@incorporation)
    end
end
```

Full disclosure regarding my controller: the above `update` is from my `incorporations_controller` even though I'm updating my `Company` model.  `Company has_one :incorporation`.  I did this because, in the larger context of my app, it made my associations much cleaner.

Comment: Can you please show us the code on you **def update**

Comment: @Lymuel thanks for the response.  I have updated my question with my update method.  From your request, I gather that validation should, theoretically, be loading the page with the submitted data upon failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your controller to this

```
def update
    @incorporation = Incorporation.find(params[:id])
    @company = @incorporation.company
    begin
        @company.name="#{params[:company][:names_attributes].values.first["name_string"]} #{params[:company][:names_attributes].values.first["suffix"]}"
    rescue NoMethodError
        @company.name="Company #{@company.id} (Untitled)"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        if @company.update(company_params)
            format.html { redirect_to({:action => "index"})}
        else
            format.html{render :edit}
            format.json { render json: @incorporation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The above is working but now, if there's an exception it directs to the show route `/incorporations/3` with `:edit` rendered (I don't have any real problem with that in itself).  But when I attempt to save from this, it seems determined to redirect to the index, regardless of whether what I enter is valid or not.  It also doesn't matter what I ask it to render in `update`.  Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: All I thought you would like to redirect it to your **index** after successful saving, use this to go to your **show** `format.html { redirect_to @incorporation}` instead of `format.html { redirect_to({:action => "index"})}`

Comment: I actually tried that.  The problem is that it seems to be redirecting to the index even if the save isn't successful and regardless of where I direct it.

Comment: Never mind, the issue had to do with my routing for this particular form.  Thanks a lot, your solution was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the correct answer, you can clean up your code quite a bit:

```
def update
    @incorporation = Incorporation.find params[:id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @incorporation.update company_params
        format.html { redirect_to({:action => "index"})}
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @incorporation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

If you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, you definitely should *not* hack the associated objects on the front-end.

You should look up [`fat model, skinny controller`](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/) (let the model do the work):

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :set_name
  attr_accessor :name_string, :name_suffix

  private

  def set_name
    if name_string && name_suffix
      self[:name] = "#{name_string} #{name_suffix}"
    else
      self[:name] = "Company #{id} (Untitled)"
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to populate the `name` of the `company. To edit your nested/associated objects directly is an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern); a hack which will later come back to haunt you.

---

The key from the answer is: `render :edit`

*Rendering* the edit view means that your current `@company` / `@incorporation` data is maintained.

*Redirecting* will invoke a new instance of the `controller`, overriding the `@incorporation`, hence what you see on your front-end.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the answer.  I've been thinking it would be a good idea to populate the name in the model.  Then only reason I haven't yet is because several controllers reference this model and only one of them needs to do this process of assignment.  (Reason being that during the incorporation process, a company can have many possible names that need to be checked out using a trademark search) But now that I'm doing validations, it might be time to sort that out.

Comment: If you give me some context, I'll write some code if you want. The trick is to always make sure your code is reusable; your controller code wasn't, and was hacky. That hackiness can end up breaking your app, and you'll have absolutely no clue why (then spending hours trying to fix it).

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I think I've got a solution.  I'm using `attr_accessor` to create an attribute `:context` that specifies what controller I'm using.  Based on that value, I perform the necessary controller-specific operations in the model.

Comment: I was going to recommend that! Thanks for the reply

Comment: Hah!  The student has become the master. (at least for now)  :-D  ...but if you were looking for a puzzle, I AM currently banging my head against another validation-related issue that I just posted.  (no pressure of course)